# How long does it take for the COVID-19 antibody to disappear?

Tags: covid-19, immune-system, infection, virus

I saw [a news article](https://www.japantimes.co.jp/news/2020/07/13/world/science-health-world/coronavirus-immunity-may-disappear-within-months-study-finds/) says; 90 days after the infection with ncov19, several patients had no detectable antibodies in their bloodstream. This seems to be one of their evidence that immunity against ncov19 does not last long.

However, as mentioned in [this thread](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/the-relationship-between-the-rate-of-decrease-of-antibody-production-and-long-te), I thought that the antibody titer in the blood would typically drop within a few months after the first infection.

So, I'd like to know the time course of blood antibody titers after infection.

> **My Question** 
> (1)How long does the high antibody titers last after the infection with the virus which causes ncov19? (In 1st infection, 2nd and subsequent infections)
> (2)What example viruses have high antibody titers that last longer? Why does a high antibody titer last longer if such a virus?

We have received feedback that the question is broad. Therefore, examples of welcomed responses are provided below.

**Examples of welcomed responses**

> - Viruses of interest in animal studies with fully controlled transmission are A, B, and C. A showed high antibody titers for XX months at the first infection and for life at the second...
> - Post-infection antibody titers evaluated at years X, XX, and XXX for patients with evidence of viral D...
> - This antibody is produced by XX.

On many stacks, discussions specific to ncov19 seems to be in progress. Therefore, I would like to discuss here from a perspective other than ncov19.

**Related stacks**
[The relationship between the rate of decrease of antibody production and long term immunity](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/24176/the-relationship-between-the-rate-of-decrease-of-antibody-production-and-long-te)

[Can you recover from COVID-19, and then be reinfected so as to be a danger to other people?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23086/can-you-recover-from-covid-19-and-then-be-reinfected-so-as-to-be-a-danger-to-ot?rq=1)

[Will COVID-19 survivors develop immunity from future infections?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/will-covid-19-survivors-develop-immunity-from-future-infections?rq=1)

[Do coronavirus antibodies give you any immunity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23301/do-coronavirus-antibodies-give-you-any-immunity)

[What would count as definitive proof that humans can develop COVID-19 immunity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23429/what-would-count-as-definitive-proof-that-humans-can-develop-covid-19-immunity?rq=1)

[Is there a virus from which humans can recover, but which doesn't grant long lasting immunity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/22901/is-there-a-virus-from-which-humans-can-recover-but-which-doesnt-grant-long-las?rq=1)

[Do coronavirus antibodies give you any immunity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23301/do-coronavirus-antibodies-give-you-any-immunity?rq=1)

[Will COVID-19 survivors develop immunity from future infections?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/will-covid-19-survivors-develop-immunity-from-future-infections?rq=1)

[Do coronavirus antibodies give you any immunity?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23301/do-coronavirus-antibodies-give-you-any-immunity?rq=1)

[What does it mean when someone has Coronavirus antibodies?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/23376/what-does-it-mean-when-someone-has-coronavirus-antibodies?rq=1)

Comment: Your two questions are _really_ broad. I think you need to focus on coronavirus instead of "typical viruses" and asking for lists of all the viruses that produce long-lasting antibodies. There are a _lot_ of viruses.

Comment: @ Carey Gregory Thanks for your comment. 　What I want to know is the overview, but we can also focus on a specific virus.

Comment: The main question as it stood was still extremely broad. Therefore I edited your question to help focus the question around covid-19 while still maintaining an element of comparison available within an answer. If you feel the need, feel free to revert your question back to how it was.

Comment: I think this question is still way way too broad - the number of bullet points makes that abundantly clear. There are also a lot of "unknowable" things asked (see the recent meta post; sorry I'm on mobile and too lazy to dig it up and link)

Comment: @ Bryan Krause Thank you for your comment.
Did this community have a metapost?　The meta-posts you said are referring to, the stacks the following page? https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a doctor, nor medical scientist. But I have read this article from pubmed: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32653658/ which leads to https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7346807/ . As you may read at the end of:

> As is well known, preexisting antibodies, memory B cells, and memory T cells are three key components against viral reinfection. Previous studies suggest that the specific memory B cell and T cell responses to SARS-CoV, which are critical for protection from reinfection, can be maintained for several years in recovered SARS patients [6]. SARS-CoV-2 is quite similar to SARS-CoV based on phylogenetic analysis, and putatively uses the same cell entry receptor. The newly discharged patients had developed SARS-CoV-2-specific T cells [4]. Potential anamnestic B cell and T cell responses existing in COVID-19 patients after recovery remain unclear. Therefore, convalescent COVID-19 patients without detectable antibodies might not indicate the loss of immunity to SARS-CoV-2 reinfection. Further studies are required to detect in large clinical trials and to evaluate the SARS-CoV-2-specific humoral and cellular immunity in COVID-19 patients and determine whether recovered patients are at risk for reinfection and would therefore benefit from vaccination.

So in other words "Further studies are required to detect in large clinical trials".